# Differential forms on tensors

Tags: differential-topology

With T: R^m -->R^n be linear transformation T(x) = B*x
and if psi sub I is an elementary alternating k-tensor on R^n, then T*psisub I has the form:

$$ T^**\psi_I $$ = sigma sub [J] cJ*psi[J] where  psiJ are the elementary alternating k-tensors on R^m and

where $I = (i_1,\ldots, i_k)$ and we can let $I_\sigma = (i_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, i_{\sigma(k)})$.

I'm trying to determine the coefficients of C sub J.

My proof:

T*f(x) = f(T(x)) = f(Bx) = ABx so the matrix T*f is AB

And if f = sigma sub [I] dsubI * psisub I is an alternating k-tensor on R^n, how can T*f be expressed in terms of the elementary k-tensors on R^m?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you write in TeX?

Comment: I'm trying to learn

Comment: What is $\phi$? What is $\psi$?

Comment: The tensors phi sub I are elementary k-tensors on V corresponding to a basis a1,...an for V.

Comment: Psi sub I = summation sub sigma (sgn sigma) * (phi sub I)^sigma where the summation extends over all sigma as an element of S sub k

Comment: Then of course the two are equal.  You have defined that $\psi_I = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\mbox{sgn} \sigma\phi_{I_\sigma}$.

Comment: Since the question has "differential forms" in the title, are you trying to figure out the details of the alternating map $A$ from $T^0_k$ to the alternating $k$-forms, $A\psi(v_1,\ldots,v_k)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\mbox{sgn}\sigma\ \psi(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})$?

Comment: Mary, after visiting [this Latex site](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), you should be able to create equations without having to write "psi sub I" etc.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, the $\phi_I$ are given by the property that $\phi_I(a_{j_1}, \ldots, a_{j_k}) = 1$ iff $(j_1, \ldots, j_k) = (i_1, \ldots, i_k)$ and $ = 0$ otherwise.

Supposing that, we have for $1 \le j_1, \ldots, j_k \le n$ 
\begin{align*}
  \phi_{I_\sigma}^\sigma(a_{j_1}, \ldots, a_{j_k})
      &= \phi_{I_\sigma}(a_{\sigma(j_1)}, \ldots, a_{j_{\sigma(j_k)}})\\
      &= \begin{cases}
                 1 & (\sigma(j_1), \ldots, \sigma(j_k)) = (\sigma(i_1), \ldots, \sigma(i_k))\\
                 0 & \text{\otherwise}
         \end{cases}\\
      &= \begin{cases}
            1 & (j_1, \ldots, j_k) = (i_1,\ldots, i_k)\\
            0 & \text{\otherwise}
         \end{cases}\\
      &= \phi_I(a_{j_1}, \ldots, a_{j_k})
\end{align*}
so $\phi_{I_\sigma}^\sigma = \phi_I$. Regarding $\psi$, I still don't understand what you want to show,

AB,